# Is there a way to generate multilingual documentation in .NET Core / .NET Standard?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xml-documentation

When I create a .NET Framework project, prompts for standard types appear in the same language as Visual Studio. With .NET Core / .NET Standard projects this is no longer the case. I've tried ways suggested on Stack Overflow (putting an additional `<summary lang="...">` comment) but couldn't get the described effect either on .NET Framework or on .NET Core.

Is this possibility available now? Is it available for any assembly or, perhaps, only for standard assemblies?